# When is the neighbourhood of a set a ball?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, pl-manifolds

In euclidean n-space, it's easy to show that given a set $S$ of radius $< r$, the $a$-neighbourhood of $S$ is a ball, for any $a \geq 2r$.

> **Proof**: Let $S$ be contained in $B_r(y)$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
>   Note that if $a \ge 2r$ then $ B_r(y) \subset Nbd_a(S)$.
>   Let $z\in Nbd_a(S) \backslash B_r(y)$.
>   Consider the triangle
>   with vertices $z$, $y$ and $s$ with $s\in S$.
>   The length of the edge $yz$ is greater than $r$ which is greater
>   than the length of the edge $ys$.
>   It follows that the angle at $z$ is less than $\pi/2$ (less than $\pi/3$, in fact),
>   which means that points on the edge $yz$ near $z$ are closer to $s$ than $z$ is,
>   which implies that these points are also in $Nbd_a(S)$.
>   Hence $Nbd_a(S)$ is star-shaped with respect to $y$.

I'd like a result for a metric $PL$ manifold, of the form:

> **Theorem**: For an metric $PL$ manifold $M$, there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that every subset $S$ of radius $r$ and all $a$ with $2r \leq a \leq \epsilon$, the neighbourhood $Nbd_a(S)$ is homeomorphic to a ball.

Can someone provide a proof?

Comment: The corresponding theorem for compact Riemannian manifolds just asks that $\epsilon$ be a bit smaller than the injectivity radius, and that on $\epsilon$ balls the geodesic coordinates don't distort angles much.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that PL should be important here, or is it just that in the situation you care about, you have a PL manifold?

Comment: I can think of more than one thing that you might mean by "metric PL manifold".

Comment: @Tom, I had in mind a simplicial manifold, with each simplex inheriting a metric from a linear embedding in R^n, although I don't really mind polyhedra more complicated that simplices.

Comment: @Dan, this will be used as a lemma inside a larger argument, where for reasons of technical convenience we've already decided to work in the PL setting. In the current draft, in fact, we nonchalantly give the Riemannian argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question right, the answer is no. Make a triangulated $2$-manifold with Euclidean metrics on the simplices, such that the total angle around some vertex is very small. Let $S$ consist of two points, both of which are the same small distance $D$ from that vertex and (subject to that) as far from each other as possible. If $2r$ is the distance between the points then for a pretty big range of values of $a$ the union of $a$-balls centered at these two points is topologically an annulus.

Comment: Hmmm, sure. What if I asked that there's some $\epsilon$, as above, and also some $k>0$, so the condition holds for $rk \leq a \leq \epsilon$? I think that would also suffice for my application.

Comment: In that same example, no matter what $a$ and $r$ are, there will always be a set (in fact, a point) of radius $<r$ whose $a$-neighborhood is topologically an annulus.

Comment: So essentially Tom's example is when your "Riemannian manifold" has a conic singularity and no lower bound on the injectivity radius. 

Comment: Hence replacing 2r with kr for some constant k. The idea is that k would be determined by the "narrowest" cone point. 

Comment: Let me make sure of the quantifiers. You seem to want a single $\epsilon$ and $k$ such that for every $r$, for every $a$ such that $rk\le a\le\epsilon$, the $a$-nbhd of a set having radius $r$ is a ball? But this fails in the cone example: go close enough to the singularity so that a "ball" of radius $a$ hits itself, and choose $r<a/k$, and let your set be a point.

Comment: Indeed. I've been confused: thanks!